# react-router-redux cannot push new URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am attempting to redirect inside a redux action when an error occurs. I've tried setting up react-router-redux but I'm getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at middleware.js:29
    at index.js:14
    at index.js:100
    at dispatch (applyMiddleware.js:45)
    at reports-actions.js:88
    at index.js:11
    at Object.dispatch (index.js:100)
    at ReportTemplate.componentWillMount (ReportTemplate.js:54)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:348
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
```

This is how the router and redux is being setup.

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
    customer: transactionTrackerCustomerReducer,
    hierarchy: transactionTrackerHierarchyReducer,
    item: transactionTrackerItemReducer,
    tender: transactionTrackerTenderReducer,
    transaction: transactionTrackerTransactionReducer,
    transactionTracker: transactionTrackerReducer,
    session: userSessionReducer,
    reports: reportsReducer
});
const middleware = applyMiddleware(createLogger(), thunk, routerMiddleware(hashHistory));
const store = createStore(reducers, compose(middleware));
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={hashHistory}>
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getBrandTheme()}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <Route path="/" render={props => (<App/>)}/>
                </Switch>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I'm trying to use it like this

```
export function fetchStoreHierarchy() {

    return function (dispatch) {

        // other code ....
        dispatch(push('/login'));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From **[`react-router-redux`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) version 4**, you have to import `routerActions`, as follows:

```
import { routerActions } from 'react-router-redux'
```

And call it's [push](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#pushlocation-replacelocation-gonumber-goback-goforward) function, as:

```
return function (dispatch) {
    // other code ....
    dispatch(routerActions.push('/login'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting error because there's no push method defined..... try calling routeActions.push('/login') like this...

```
import { routeActions } from 'react-router-redux';
dispatch(routeActions.push('/login'));
```